# Reproducing CRAN check unit test issue on Windows: "Error: DLL 'vctrs' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?"

Tags: r, cran, testthat

A CRAN package submission has produced an error running a few of the testthat unit tests and only on the Windows platform:

- https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/nhlapi_0.1.3_20210218_132343/Windows/00check.log
- with the culprit seemingly being: `Error: DLL 'vctrs' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture`

I cannot reproduce the issue via:

- running on R-Hub where all seems fine: https://builder.r-hub.io/status/nhlapi_0.1.3.tar.gz-c2eabc85c5a54ac1a6ec86b36f958db0
- on my local Windows machine, where all tests also run fine via R CMD check

Can someone recommend a way to debug and resolve these kind of issues?

FWIW: nothing has changed in the tested pieces of code that produce the errors since the last checks which were successful and I have reasonable confidence that the tests should not be failing.

Comment: Same problem for me. Package gastempt was accepted before on CRAN

Comment: You should take this to R-pkg-devel. There is already a report of another recent issue with CRAN's Windows builder.

Comment: I added vcrts to LinkingTo, same error on CRAN build

Comment: I read the latest messages on https://www.mail-archive.com/r-package-devel@r-project.org/ , and it looks like even GrandMasters like JimHesters have similar problems with their Windows build currently. Probably it would be best to wait a few days and retry then.

Comment: I reported it with a link to this thread on r-package-evel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Uwe Ligges, this is fixed on CRAN now

https://www.mail-archive.com/r-package-devel@r-project.org/msg06553.html